# Cannot update Data in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What I want to do is, check first if the ID number exist, then if it exist then do the updating process, but the problem is, it does not update. What is the problem ?

```
sqlconn = New MySqlConnection
sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password='';database=innovative"
Try
    sqlconn.Open()
    query = "SELECT Full_Name FROM employee WHERE ID='" & txt_id_number.Text & "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid ID number please secure that the  ID number is already Exist" & vbNewLine & "TAKE NOTE:" & vbNewLine & "You cannot update or change the existing ID number for it is the primary Key for the Employee, If you want to Change it, its better to delete the Employee then add it again." & vbNewLine & "Other than that you can change the Full name, age, contact and etc.", vbCritical)

    Else
        reader.Close()
        sqlconn.Open()
        query1 = "UPDATE employee SET Full_Name ='" & txt_fullname.Text & "', Employee_Type='" & txt_employee_type.Text & "', Age='" & txt_age.Text & "',Sex='" & cb_sex.Text & "', Status='" & txt_status.Text & "', Contact ='" & txt_contact.Text & "',E_mail='" & txt_email.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & txt_id_number.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query1, sqlconn)
        reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        MsgBox(txt_fullname.Text & " was successfully updated", vbInformation)
        txt_age.Text = ""
        txt_contact.Text = ""
        txt_email.Text = ""
        txt_employee_type.Text = ""
        txt_fullname.Text = ""
        txt_id_number.Text = ""
        txt_status.Text = ""
        cb_sex.Text = ""
        add_employee()
    End If
    sqlconn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    sqlconn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: A reader object is used to Query a database, for Update, Insert & Delete statements you want to executeNonQuery.

Comment: You can also get rid of your query looking for a valid id and return the number of rows updated when you execute the update statement. If 0 is returned, then that WHERE condition found no rows to update. Anything greater than 0 means that the WHERE condition was met. Also, you should stop concatenating values into your statements and use parameters to both secure your sql statements and make you life easier when it comes to knowing how to wrap fields based on their type.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yep... at the very least you could do a {textboxnamehere}.text = {textboxnamehere}.text.replace("'", "''") to replace the single quote with two single qoutes and remove the ability to escape the value parameter.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael That is not a good way to protect against sql injection. I used to do it too, when I was a new programmer, but that doesn't make it okay.

Comment: If you read my statement fully... you would see that I said... at the very least...  I'm not sure he would have been ready to use store d procedures and params

Comment: Thank You for all your comment guys ;) Im just new at mySQL programming, and maybe I need more day to study it haha ;) Anyways thanks again, I'll study all you comments that would help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private sqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Private query, query1 As String
    Private cmd As MySqlCommand
    Private reader As MySqlDataReader

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        sqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password='';database=innovative"
        Try
            sqlconn.Open()
            query = "SELECT Full_Name FROM employee WHERE ID='" & txt_id_number.Text & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconn)
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows = False Then
                MsgBox("Invalid ID number please secure that the  ID number is already Exist" & vbNewLine & "TAKE NOTE:" & vbNewLine & "You cannot update or change the existing ID number for it is the primary Key for the Employee, If you want to Change it, its better to delete the Employee then add it again." & vbNewLine & "Other than that you can change the Full name, age, contact and etc.", vbCritical)
            Else
              query1 = "UPDATE employee SET Full_Name = @txt_fullname, Employee_Type=txt_employee_type, Age=@txt_age'" 
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query1, sqlconn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@txt_fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txt_fullname.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@txt_employee_type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txt_employee_type.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@txt_age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txt_age.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox(txt_fullname.Text & " was successfully updated", vbInformation)
                txt_age.Text = ""
                txt_contact.Text = ""
                txt_email.Text = ""
                txt_employee_type.Text = ""
                txt_fullname.Text = ""
                txt_id_number.Text = ""
                txt_status.Text = ""
                cb_sex.Text = ""
                add_employee()
            End If
            sqlconn.Close()
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            sqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: is correct.... you can't use a cmd.ExecuteReader to perform a Non-query transaction.  You only use Reader when you are pulling data, not when you are inserting, updating, or deleting.

Comment: Thanks For this. Haha. Im just new at mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to change.

1. Use cmd.[ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_3) for Insert or Update queries.
2. Do not use conn.[Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) again when it is not closed; It returns 'Connection is already open' error and execution will terminate to catch block. *This is the reason why your code didnt work.*
3. [Parameterize](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBAPI/System.Data.SqlClient/NewSqlParameter.htm) the queries for security and type-casting.

Happy coding!

Comment: To add to item 2):  If at any point in your code, you can't be sure of the status of the connection (open/close) you can check `if sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Open` prior to trying open it again.